# AWK - compare column $1 , append rows together that match (including duplicates)

Tags: awk

I'm trying to parse two csv files that contains thousands of rows. The data is to be matched and appended based solely on the data in the first column. I currently have it parsing the files and outputting to 3 files:

```
1 - key matched
2 - file1 only
3 - file2 only
```

The issue I am having is that I have noticed once it makes one match it move on to the next line rather than finding the other entries. for the data in question I would rather output multiple lines containing some duplicates than to miss nay data. (The name column for instance varies depending on who entered the data)

**INPUT FILES**

```
file1.csv
topic,group,name,allow
fishing,boaties,dave,yes
fishing,divers,steve,no
flying,red,luke,yes
walking,red,tom,yes

file2.csv
Resource,name,email,funny
fishing,frank,frank@home.com,no
swiming,lee,lee@wallbanger.com,no
driving,lee,lee@wallbanger.com,no
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
key matched
topic,group,name,allow,Resource,name,email,funny
fishing,divers,steve,no,fishing,frank,frank@home.com,no

file1_only
topic,group,user,allow
fishing,divers,steve,no
flying,red,luke,yes
walking,red,tom,yes

file2_only
Resource,user,email,funny
swiming,lee,lee@wallbanger.com,no
driving,lee,lee@wallbanger.com,no
```

**Expected Output**

```
key matched
topic,group,name,allow,Resource,name,email,funny
fishing,divers,steve,no,fishing,frank,frank@home.com,no
fishing,boaties,dave,yes,fishing,frank,frank@home.com,no

file1_only
topic,group,user,allow
flying,red,luke,yes
walking,red,tom,yes

file2_only
Resource,user,email,funny
swiming,lee,lee@wallbanger.com,no
driving,lee,lee@wallbanger.com,no
```

So for every key in file 1 column 1, it needs to output/append every key that matches in file2 column1.

This is my current awk filter. Im guessing I need to add a loop in if possible?

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
FNR==1 { next }
{ key = $1 }
NR==FNR {
    file1[key] = $0
    next
}
key in file1 {
    print file1[key], $0 > "./out_combined.csv"
    delete file1[key]
    next
}
{
    print > "./out_file2_only.csv"
}
END {
    for (key in file1) {
        print file1[key] > "./out_file1_only.csv"
    }
}
```

Comment: are keys in file2 column1 unique?

Comment: no, nothing is unique currently as these csv files have been built from parsing numerous log files. A bit of an audit exercise.

Comment: what is desired output if file2.csv also contains an additional line `fishing,x,y@z,no` ?

Comment: how many lines in the input? Thousands? Millions? Trillions? How much RAM on the machine doing the processing? Do you care about the order of the output lines?

Comment: btw, `file1.csv[key]` should be a syntax error

Comment: "what is desired output if file2.csv also contains an additional line fishing,x,y@z,no"  To output that line as well

Comment: re: files size  < 10,000 lines

Comment: @jhnc I corrected the syntax errors, incorrect use of `>>` and missing `delete` that must be present to get the posted current output.

Comment: @EdMorton Hey ed, this is a followup to the question from last week, is there  away to link to that ? I didnt see anything on that page to do that . Or is it simply to add in the url?

Comment: @Waldonutz just copy/paste the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
FNR==1 {
    if ( NR==FNR ) {
        file1hdr = $0
    }
    else {
        print file1hdr     > "./out_file1_only.csv"
        print              > "./out_file2_only.csv"
        print file1hdr, $0 > "./out_combined.csv"
    }
    next
}
{ key = $1 }
NR==FNR {
    file1[key,++cnt[key]] = $0
    next
}
{
    file2[key]
    if ( key in cnt ) {
        for ( i=1; i<=cnt[key]; i++ ) {
            print file1[key,i], $0 > "./out_combined.csv"
        }
    }
    else {
        print > "./out_file2_only.csv"
    }
}
END {
    for ( key in cnt ) {
        if ( !(key in file2) ) {
            for ( i=1; i<=cnt[key]; i++ ) {
                print file1[key,i] > "./out_file1_only.csv"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1.csv file2.csv
```

```
$ head out_*
==> out_combined.csv <==
topic,group,name,allow,Resource,name,email,funny
fishing,boaties,dave,yes,fishing,frank,frank@home.com,no
fishing,divers,steve,no,fishing,frank,frank@home.com,no

==> out_file1_only.csv <==
topic,group,name,allow
flying,red,luke,yes
walking,red,tom,yes

==> out_file2_only.csv <==
Resource,name,email,funny
swiming,lee,lee@wallbanger.com,no
driving,lee,lee@wallbanger.com,no
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, works perfectly.